# Highlighter Alternative Using Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm currently using a bootstrap 3 typeahead module from

https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

When a user searches, sometimes the suggestion returned does not actually contain any of the text they are searching for.

For example, a user could be searching for `Athletic Clothing` and my search suggestion algorithm may return `Nike` to TypeAhead.

Everything is good, except I'm overriding the TypeAhead display by specifying the `highlighter` function it should use to display the data.

It appears the highlighter function is only called when the users search text is present in the suggestion item. So in this case, my `Nike` search suggestion is not being displayed by the `highlighter` function.

Is there a way to force the highlighter function upon every typeahead element? Even those not containing the users query.

This is my highlighter function:

```
highlighter: function(data){
                var itm = ''
                         + "<div class='typeahead_wrapper'>"
                         + "<a href='/users.php?user="+data+"'><img width='30' class='typeahead_photo' src='/profiles/" + data + ".jpg' /></a>"
                         + "<div class='typeahead_labels'>"
                         + "<div class='typeahead_primary'><a href='/users.php?user="+data+"'>" + data + "</a></div>"
                         + "</div>"
                         + "</div>";
                return itm;
            }
```

Comment: Twitter bootstrap doesn't have a typeahead component (at least not in v3). Please specify the library that you're using.

Comment: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Comment: @BelginFish: I know this post is pretty old. But does bootstrap-typeahead still have the problem you mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a very poor method to solve the issue.

I modified the data being returned to typeahead to be in the format

```
value**matched text
```

Then at the top of the highlighter function I simply called `split` to extract the value from it before outputting.